# Can I submit a Pull Request to an inexistent branch?

Tags: git, github

I want to submit a pull request to a `gh-pages` branch of an upstream repo. The `gh-pages` branch was **NOT** created on the upstream repo.

Is it possible to open the PR so that if merged, the `gh-pages` branch is automatically created and and merged in?

This is what I get using GitHub:
[image: GH]

Do I need to ask the repo's owner to create the branch first then open the PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull requests are for updating existing branches. They cannot create new branches.

You can think about it as using `git pull`, which as its man page describes:

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch.

So if you want to put your work in an upstream `gh-pages` branch, you will need someone with write access to create it there first.

---

And since it looks like you're trying to set up GitHub Pages, there are some alternatives to `gh-pages` that may work in your situation:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages